# How can I remove zero and negative values in data frame?

Tags: r

I have a data frame, I want to delete negative and zero values in the column of X. How can I do it?

```
b=data.frame(
  x=c(1,2,0,-1,4,50,8,NA),
  Y=c(1:8))
```

I wrote this code but it was false.
`(b[,1]<=0)=NA`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact you can simply do

```
b[b<=0] <- NA
```

resulting in

```
> b
   x Y
1  1 1
2  2 2
3 NA 3
4 NA 4
5  4 5
6 50 6
7  8 7
8 NA 8
```